# Can't find a variable atob

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

Screen1.js

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react'
import {View,Text} from 'react-native'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import '@firebase/firestore';

const Screen1 = props =>{

    useEffect(() => 
    {
        var dbh = firebase.firestore().collection("Jots").doc("note");
        dbh.set({name:"pradeep"}) //The yellow warning is popped up in this line.
    }); 

    return(
             <View>
                <Text>Title</Text>
             </View>
    )
}
```

console

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: atob]

Stack trace:
  node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.cjs.js:23101:0 in <global>
  http://192.168.0.108:19001/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:131203:60 in fromBase64String
```

I just followed the guide in the expo documentation but still don't know why this problem is occurring. Need a clear explanation on this. And also what is atob variable?

Comment: Unless some package happens to name something else like that, `atob` is a function to decode a Base64 encoded String. `btoa`, on the other hand, encodes a String to Base64 ([Base64 encoding and decoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding))

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why does this atob warning is shown here in the console? Can you figure out the issue here in the code?

Comment: Pronably because the atob function is part of `window` in the browser env, which isn't available unless specifically ported over. You could try and download an NPM module.

Comment: For React Native use [`react-native-firebase`](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/).

Comment: can someone explain how to connect to firestore and why atob is happening?

Comment: Same issue, did you find a solution? @Pradeep

Comment: To see why this is happening check out Github fix which is not integrated yet: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/2677

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I have tried downgrading but that's not resulted as a solution to me. I don't know why.

The global import of **base64** in the **app.js** resolved this problem.

```
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'

if (!global.btoa) {  global.btoa = encode }

if (!global.atob) { global.atob = decode }
```

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: I upgraded but did nothing with firebase 7.9.3. This solution fixed it for me.

Comment: also got the same with `7.11.0`, answer resolves the issue

Comment: Same here with `7.14.0`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution worked for me, while facing same issue with 7.14.0!

Comment: Thank you for your code. This is my solution for this error.

Comment: For TypeScript I had to add `const globalAny: any = global;` to make it work and then use the `globalAny` field instead of `global`.

Comment: This seems to be an issue again in firebase 7.14.3, only the above solution no longer remedies the problem

Answer (score 11):

Worked for me ! Thanks papay0, there is indeed something wrong with version 7.9.1.

```
npm install firebase@7.9.0
expo r -c # restard expo without cache
```

You can `rm -rf ./node_modules/ && npm i`

Answer (score 7):

I found a workaround, I still there is a bug on their side.
They just released 2 days ago version 7.9.1.
Try to use 7.9.0.

> yarn add firebase@7.9.0

I am creating an issue for it, follow [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2667).

Comment: thanks for the response still the downgrading to the lower version doesn't help. It stillsays 'can't find variable atob'.

Comment: should I wrap the JSON with atob?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Pradeep. This worked for me on firebase 7.14.1:

```
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'

if (!global.btoa) {  global.btoa = encode }

if (!global.atob) { global.atob = decode }
```

and using import like this

> ```
> import firebase from 'firebase';
> import 'firebase/firestore'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The atob function is part of the JavaScript window object and is not available in React Native.

To decode base64-encoded data in React Native, you can use the base-64 library